# Adjusting the ANOVA values when a Blocking is added

Tags: statistics

the following is the incomplete table that I am supposed to fill out.

[image]

I was given a one-way ANOVA table with $SSE = 186.53$ and the rest of the values being the same except that there was not error row.  I was also given that the new model has a block effect with $SS_{Block}=80$ in a Randomized Complete Block Design.

My understanding of an RCBD is that the error term is split into a block effect and a smaller error effect. That is how I got $SSE = 106.53$ for the new one.

And here is my question.  I know that the degree of freedom of the original one was 25 for the error effect, but for the new design, I only know that it has to be less than 25.

How do we figure out what the df for Error is with this much information given?

Do we need more information?